# Lync client SDK reports wrong status code

Tags: c#, silverlight, skype-for-business, lync-client-sdk

My silverlight 5 application, running in IE, has successfully been integrated with the local Lync client for a year or two, happily fetching lych contacts. Now this is suddenly misbehaving. I get the status `ClientState.SignedOut` even though the lync user *is currently signed in* when my application starts up.

```
timer = new DispatcherTimer();
timer.Tick += delegate(object s, EventArgs args)
{
   LyncClient client = LyncClient.GetClient();
   if (client != null && client.State == ClientState.SignedIn)
   {
       timer.Stop();
       // do stuff
       //  --- never happens, client.state is SignedOut even though
       //      the lync client user is signed in :(
```

I have tried to wait and poll for status for a while after having created the lync client proxy. Didn't help. I also tried to subscribe to status changes and then sign the lync client out and in again while my appication is running. That did help for some users but is not a feasable solution.

My Lync client was recently upgraded to 'Skype for Business' (Microsoft Lync (c) 2013 (15.0.4737.1000), but things appearently did work after the initial upgrade, so it's unclear if this is the culprit. I've tried both the 2010 and the 2015 Lync Client SDK. Same strange behavhiour using both,

I'm stumped.

Thanks,

Comment: Update: I tried to simply ignore the erroneous 'SignedOut' state and go ahead and load the contacts anyway. Seems to work...

Comment: Update II: Answer from Micrsoft on the MSDN forum: "This was broken in the July 14, 2015 update. It is a known issue that, as far as I know, is set to be resolved in the next update."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this is a newly introduced bug in Windows/IE/Lync. See my comments above for source and workaround.